# Given a transient Markov chain with state space $S$, what is $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \sum_{y \in S} \Pi^n (x, y)$?

Tags: probability, markov-chains

Given an irreducible and transient Markov chain, we know that $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \Pi^n (x, y) = 0$ for all pairs $x, y \in S$.

However, we also know that $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \sum_{y \in S} \Pi^n (x, y) = 1$ too. How is this limit possible, since every term in the summation converges to $0$ a.s.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a finite state space irreducibale MC you cannot have transient states. If the state space is infinite there is no contradiction. For example,  $ \sum\limits_{k=1}^{n} \frac 1 n =1$ and each term tends to $0$. That is not a contradiction becuase you cannot take the limit inside the sum.